# launch a view controller directly from a navigation view controller in a tab-based app

Tags: iphone, ios

It's a tab-based app, in AppDelegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: it init all view controllers for the tabs. One of it is the app's "Setting" view controller, which is a navigation controller.

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         favoritesViewController, 
                                         mapController, 
                                         messagesController, 
                                         picker, 
                                         navController, 
                                         nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

[self.window addSubview:_navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

There is a service activation view stacked in the settings controller, but for the 1st time user (detected by plist), I want to launch the activation view directly.

I tried

```
if ([settings objectForKey:kClientId] == nil) {
    ActivateServiceViewController *activateServiceViewController = [[ActivateServiceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivateServiceViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:activateServiceViewController animated:YES];        
}
```

It didn't work. Anyway to do that?

Comment: @makaron, lol do not be too arrogant, i never expect u to guve help.

Comment: thank you is added as vote, not verbally in this community. get used to it! otherwise it's just like thousands other forum. Like to help or not, it's all your call. If you are not willing, or not able to, just skip it. How hard is that?

Comment: No, that's not hard. And generally speaking you're right, but there's always 'but', you know? Most of stackoverflow users (note, 'users', not only active participants) will agree, that it's much more convenient to search at the page the correct answer for your question among 20 of them, if it's marked as actually helpful (and I think you'll agree with this too in a bit of time, if you didn't yet). It spares a *lot* of time. And this is basically the thing, in which this forum is a bit different from the thousand of others.Therefore, yes, 'thanks' here is a kinda 'must be' commitment to forum

Comment: @makaron: Why an user with 700 reputation has the ball to tell people off like you did? StackOverFlow is notorious for being rude/arrogant against newbies, but to think that newcomers like you are so quickly adapting its bad behaviour is really an absurd idea. There's nothing wrong with Espina's question and if you can't answer it, you leave it alone. Easy enough?